# How to find out what is waking up my computer?

Tags: windows-10

I often find that I put my computer to sleep, and find it next morning with exhausted battery. Or just open the lid a bit later to find it awake. Or suddenly in the middle of the night my cooler wakes me up. Something is bringing it out of sleep. How to find out what? All of the `powercfg -requests` show `None`.

Dell XPS 9560
Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer keeps waking from sleep without any obvious reason](https://superuser.com/questions/1305652/my-computer-keeps-waking-from-sleep-without-any-obvious-reason)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open an Admin Command prompt.

Type:   powercfg  /lastwake

This gives you what you need.  Powercfg /?  for help

Once you know what time, that may help you determine the reason.

Follow up note: For irregular (i.e. not normal) activities, look in Admin Tools, Event Viewer, System log for the times you got above from Powercfg.  Event Viewer does not track updates, so just abnormal activities.

Comment: We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but this question has already been asked a **lot**. Next time, before you post please take a minute to search Super User for potential duplicates before authoring an answer to what is undoubtedly a very common question.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look. The ones I did look at (and have before) had no accepted answers.  One now does.

Comment: But that doesn't mean that it is **not** a duplicate question.  When a previous Q&A has literally *thousands* of views and both the query and the answer are essentially the same, it really is a disservice to the community to support yet another one with a "new" answer rather marking it as a duplicate.

Comment: I try to see what is available, but I do avoid year or more older questions since so much has changed in the last 12 months. You may delete my answer if you wish to do so.

Comment: I wouldn't automatically dismiss questions that are more than a year old.  Quite often, they are still pertinent and it's much better to have one high-quality, canonical Q&A than repeatedly answer what is essentially the same question on an annual basis.